# How can I open a terminal with a specific path quickly using the vscode breadcrumbs bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use the VS Code breadcrumbs bar(the bar just below the file name bar) to open a terminal with specific path quickly, like `right-click`, `ctrl-click` or other keybinding shortcuts. Is it possible? Is there other way to open a terminal with specific path quickly?

I searched the settings in [VS Code code navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved), but didn't get what I want.

Comment: would it solve your problem to just use the `File: Copy Path of Active File` command in the command palette and then paste the copied text into a `cd` command in the terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I didn't find the option you mentioned. 
Mac vscode Version: 1.78.2 (Universal).

Comment: did you use in [the command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to open a new terminal while changing to the active file's directory, then use this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",              // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [

      "workbench.action.terminal.new",    // open a new terminal
      {
        // send the cd current file directory command to the new terminal
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "cd '${fileDirname}'\u000D"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`\u000D` is a `return` so the `cd` command runs immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to @starball 's suggestion, there exists a default(maybe) keybinding shortcut `cmd K` + `P`(MacOS) to copy the path of the active file.

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k p",
  "command": "workbench.action.files.copyPathOfActiveFile"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way with breadcrumbs, but there are at least two workarounds:

- Right click the folder/directory in the Explorer View and then click "Open in Integrated Terminal". This may be easier to find if you have the `explorer.autoReveal` setting left at its default value of `true`. For this workaround, you might also be interested in this feature-request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67711.
- Use the `File: Copy Path of Active File` command in the command palette (or whatever keybinding it is bound to. I think the default is <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>). Then paste that into a `cd` command in your shell.